# Images not showing depending on the URL: with or without dash "/" in the end

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

This is really weird. The images of my website are not showing properly. If a add a slash in the end of the url, they show up, otherwise, they don't. Take a look:

This is the link with dash in the end:
http://jobbox.com.br/cocoonhealth/insurance/private-health-insurance/

To see the issue, delete the dash in the end…. the images will not show up anymore..

The funny thing is when I look at the html code, is exactly the same. I have some specific routes, but this issues is all over the website.

My routes:

view plaincopy to clipboardprint?
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{

```
// Ignore axd files such as assest, image, sitemap etc  
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");  


routes.MapRoute("ServicesIndex", "services", new { controller = "Service", action = "Index" });  

// Insurance Forms  
routes.MapRoute("InsuranceIndex", "insurance", new { controller = "Service", action = "Insurance" });  
routes.MapRoute("InsuranceForm_Corporate", "insurance/corporate-health-insurance", new { controller = "Service", action = "InsuranceCorporate" });  
routes.MapRoute("InsuranceForm_Life", "insurance/life-insurance", new { controller = "Service", action = "InsuranceLife" });  
routes.MapRoute("InsuranceForm_Private", "insurance/private-health-insurance", new { controller = "Service", action = "InsurancePrivate" });  

// Claim Forms  
routes.MapRoute("ClaimIndex", "claim", new { controller = "Service", action = "Claim" });  
routes.MapRoute("ClaimForm_PersonalInjury", "claim/personal-injury-claim", new { controller = "Service", action = "PersonalInjury" });  

// Surgery Forms  
routes.MapRoute("SurgeryIndex", "surgery", new { controller = "Service", action = "Surgery" });  
routes.MapRoute("SurgeryForm_LaserEye", "surgery/laser-eye-surgery", new { controller = "Service", action = "LaserEye" });  


routes.MapRoute("Cocoon.AboutUs", "about-us", new { controller = "Home", action = "AboutUs" });  
routes.MapRoute("Cocoon.ContactUs", "contact-us", new { controller = "Home", action = "ContactUs" });  

routes.MapRoute("Cocoon.Profile", "profile/{login}", new { controller = "Profile", action = "Index", login = ""  });  

routes.MapRoute(  
    "Default",                                              // Route name  
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters  
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults  
);
```

}

Also, the CSS is working propoerly and it's pointing to the same folder.
Do you know what's going on? Thank you again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of ways is to replace relative pathes with full path from

```
../../Content/Images/cocoon_health_logo.png
```

to

```
/cocoonhealth/Content/Images/cocoon_health_logo.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Your image sources do this:

```
<img height="59" width="228" title="Cocoon Health" alt="Cocoon Health" src="../../Content/Images/cocoon_health_logo.png"/>
```

This tells the browser...

```
../../Content/Images/cocoon_health_logo.png
Go Up a folder level > Go Up a folder level > Content/Images/...png
```

When you omit the / from the end of the url, you actually only need to go up one level, not two - because of the routing rule.

By Using the following

```
<img height="59" width="228" title="Cocoon Health" alt="Cocoon Health" src="/cocoonhealth/Content/Images/cocoon_health_logo.png"/>
```

You're telling the browser to...

```
/cocoonhealth/Content/Images/cocoon_health_logo.png
/(start from the root) > cocoonhealth/Content/Images/cocoon_health_logo.png
```

So this will work with and without the slash.

You can also use the BASE tag in HTML, but you should read about it first as otherwise it will surprise you!